# Spring MVC url not working

Tags: spring-mvc

I have this page welcome.jsp:

```
          <body>

                <h1>Heading</h1>
                <p>Tagline</p>
                <p align="center">
                    <c:url var="homeLink" value="/home" />
                    <a href="${homeLink}" class="btn btn-success btn-large disabled">Get
                        Us Feeds Now</a>
                </p>


         </body>
         </html>
```

But when I click the link, I am not moving to home.jsp 
Controller for home.jsp is:

```
     @Controller
     @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
     public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm() {
    System.out.println("Called");

    return "home";
}
  }
```

Config.xml:

```
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

<!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views 
    directory -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Please note that my pages are in webcontent folder only, not in web-inf.

I am really stuck in this problem. Please help me out...

Comment: can you paste your config.xml also?

Comment: I have added config.xml.

Comment: where is this jsp file located? if it is under /WEB-INF then you need to give `<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />`

Comment: Have you tried putting the jsp files in /WEB-INF/views as per the comment in your xml?

Comment: As I have mentioned in the problem statement, the jsp files are directly under web content folder only. They are not in web inf folder or webinf/views folder. Please ignore the comment in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your controller is called or not, but I am trying my best

**1. If controller not called:**

Check web.xml and give url pattern as /

```
change if you have like this
   <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
to
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

**2. If controller called:**

```
Give suffix value (path of your jsps) of your view resolver as

  /WEB-INF/views or any other
```